# how to install nvidia driver on incognito livecd

Tags: linux, drivers, privacy

I tried [incognito](http://www.anonymityanywhere.com/incognito/) and it's great, but i have one issue... it's killing my eyes. When this happens on other livecds i usually just install nvidia driver and everything's fine. But on incognito:

1. When i check mnt and media folders there's nothing there. Is incognito not detecting my hard drives or do i need to mount them from console first somehow? I mean - I need to access my hd to run driver installer -_-
2. How do i kill X so i could install nvidia driver? Init 3 doesn't do anything and killall just restarts X server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merry Christmas!

1. I'm not familiar with Incognito offhand but it sounds as if it's not automounting the drives.  (This is different than detecting them.)
   You should be able to mount them from the console with the standard `mount` command.
2. You can restart the X server with Ctrl-Alt-Backspace as well as what you mentioned.  X should reread its configuration files on restart, so you should be able to perform any necessary reconfiguring steps, then restart the X server to test your changes.
   Incognito may be using GDM/KDM (or a similar login manager), which would explain why X automatically restarts and doesn't die when you kill it.  Shut down the login manager, then you should be able to kill X.  (`/etc/init.d/gdm stop` is the command for Ubuntu; Incognito should be similar.  KDM/XDM/etc will be similar.)
   As a final option, try switching to runlevel 1 -- on Debian-based distros, runlevels 2-5 are all graphical multiuser runlevels (they're configured identically).  `init 1` should do this for you.